# Sorting in grid panel

Tags: extjs

```
    var store = new FMP.AspNetJsonStore({
        fields: [
                       { name: 'AssetID' },
                       { name: 'AssociationID' },
                       { name: 'Image' },
                       { name: 'StatusName' },
                       { name: 'ModelName' },
                       { name: 'IPAddress' },
                       { name: 'InScope', type: 'boolean' },
                       { name: 'ServicePlanName' },
                       { name: 'PricePlanName' },
                       { name: 'PricePlanDescription' },
                       { name: 'Program' },
                       { name: 'ServicePlanID' },
                       { name: 'Customer' },
                       { name: 'Black', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'Cyan', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'Magenta', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'Yellow', type: 'float' },
                       { name: 'BlackPct' },
                       { name: 'CyanPct' },
                       { name: 'MagentaPct' },
                       { name: 'YellowPct' },
                       { name: 'PrinterMarkerSupplies' },
                       { name: 'PageCount' },
                       { name: 'BlackImpressions' },
                       { name: 'ColorImpressions' },
                       { name: 'PricePlanID' },
                       { name: 'ResponsibilityForAction' },
                       { name: 'PrinterSerialNumber' }

                    ],

        totalProperty: "TotalCount",
        autoLoad: { params: { start: 0, limit: myPageSize} },
        //autoLoad: true,
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            // Call web service method using GET syntax
            url: 'GetPrintersGrid.asmx/buildGrid',
            // Ask for Json response
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
            method: "GET"
        }),
        remoteSort: true,
        //sortInfo: { field: 'PageCount', direction: "DESC" },
        groupField: 'Customer',
        root: 'Records'
    });

    store.setDefaultSort('PageCount', 'DESC');
```

I am using a webservice to sort this.

I am getting an error

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: DESC.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromGetRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

Can anyone help me in this issue

I am using Ext.ux.AspWebServiceProxy class and used this proxy class in the store.Also defined the webservice in the user control in scriptmanager proxy
Iam getting an error saying GetPrintersGrid is undefined.Iam using the follwing example for reference.

http://osman.in/aspnet/using-extjs-grid-with-aspnet-ajax-wcf-webservices-c/

Can you please help me in this issue.

```
/// <reference path="ExtJS/ext-all.js" />

Ext.namespace('Ext.ux');

Ext.ux.AspWebServiceProxy = function(conn)
           {
              Ext.ux.AspWebServiceProxy.superclass.constructor.call(this);
              Ext.apply(this, conn);
           };

Ext.extend(Ext.ux.AspWebServiceProxy, Ext.data.DataProxy, 
{
     load : function (params, reader, callback, scope, arg)
            {
               var userContext = {
                                    callback: callback, 
                                    reader: reader, 
                                    arg: arg, 
                                    scope: scope
                                 };

               var proxyWrapper = this;

               //Handles the response we get back from the web service call
               var webServiceCallback = function(response, context, methodName) 
                                        { 
                                            proxyWrapper.loadResponse(response, userContext, methodName); 
                                        }

               var serviceParams = [];

               //Convert the params into an array of values so that they can be used in the call (note assumes that the properties on the object are in the correct order)
               for (var property in params)
               {
                  serviceParams.push(params[property]);
               }

               //Add the webservice callback handlers
               serviceParams.push(webServiceCallback);
               serviceParams.push(this.handleErrorResponse);

               //Make the actual ASP.Net web service call
               this.webServiceProxyMethod.apply(this.webServiceProxy, serviceParams); 
            },

     handleErrorResponse : function(response, userContext, methodName)
                           {
                              alert("Error while calling method: " + methodName + "\n" + response.get_message());
                           },

     loadResponse : function (response, userContext, methodName)
                    {
                        var result = userContext.reader.readRecords(response);
                        userContext.callback.call(userContext.scope, result, userContext.arg, true);
                    }

});

var dataStore = new Ext.data.Store(
                    {
                        //Note that I have renamed the web service proxy class
                        proxy: new Ext.ux.AspWebServiceProxy(
                        {
                            webServiceProxy: GetPrintersGrid,
                            webServiceProxyMethod:  GetPrintersGrid.buildGrid
                        }),
                       remoteSort: true                       
                    });

 <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="PageScriptManager" runat="server">
        <Services>
           <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/GetPrintersGrid.asmx" />
</Services>
        <Scripts>
              <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Ext.ux.AspWebServiceProxy.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

Comment: This still is not a ExtJS problem, but you need to publish the source code for FMP.AspNetJsonStore should you get past your server problems.

Comment: Actually, this could very well be a client code issue, since the server error is about **de**serializing JSON sent from the client to the server in a web service call.  Hard to tell from what's posted though...

Answer (score 1):

This is the souce code i ussed
        FMP.AspNetJsonReader = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonReader, {

```
        read: function(response) {
            // Assuming ASP.NET encoding - Data is stored as 
            var json = response.responseText;
            var o = Ext.decode(json);
            if (!o) {
                throw { message: "AspNetJsonReader.read: Json object not found" };
            }
            if (!o.d) {
                throw { message: "AspNetJsonReader.read: Root element d not found" };
            }
            return this.readRecords(o.d);

        }

    });

    FMP.AspNetJsonStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.GroupingStore, {
        /**
        * @cfg {Ext.data.DataReader} reader @hide
        */
        constructor: function(config) {
            FMP.AspNetJsonStore.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply(config, {
                reader: new FMP.AspNetJsonReader(config)
            }));
        }
    });
```

Iam using AS.NET for server side

Here is my webservice
public PagedResult buildGrid(int start, int limit, string sortfield, string dir)
    {
        var a=5;

```
    Guid AccountID = (Guid)Session["AccountID"];
    //string sortdir;
    //if( dir == "DESC")
    //{
    //    sortdir = dir.Substring(0, 4).Trim().ToUpper();
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    sortdir = dir.Substring(0, 3).Trim().ToUpper();
    //}

    string SortExpression = sortfield + " " + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir) ? dir : String.Empty);

    //string whereClause = "SELECT value a FROM XSP_AssetList_V AS a WHERE a.AccountID = GUID'" + AccountID + "' order by a.PageCount = '" +  + "'";
    string whereClause = "SELECT value a FROM XSP_AssetList_V AS a WHERE a.AccountID = GUID'" + AccountID + "' Order By  a."+SortExpression;
    //string whereClause = "SELECT value a , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY" + " " + SortExpression + ") As RowNumber FROM XSP_AssetList_V AS a WHERE a.AccountID = GUID'" + AccountID + "'";
    //string whereClause = "SELECT value a FROM XSP_AssetList_V AS a WHERE a.AccountID = GUID'" + AccountID + "'";
    List<FMPAsset> fmpAssets = new List<FMPAsset>();



    using (XSPAssetModel.XSPAssetEntities assetEntities = new XSPAssetEntities(b.BuildEntityConnectionString1("XSMDSN")))
    {
        ObjectQuery<XSP_AssetList_V> assets = new ObjectQuery<XSP_AssetList_V>(whereClause, assetEntities);
        //var assetOrder = assets.OrderBy(x => x.StatusName).ToList();
        var assetPage = assets.Skip(start).Take(limit);

        //var totalAssetCount = assets.Count();



        currentAssets = assetPage.ToList();
        int currentAssetsCount = currentAssets.Count;
        string imgprefix = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImgPrefix"];
        char[] separators = { '/' };
        string appname = "";
        int lastloc = imgprefix.Substring(0, imgprefix.Length - 1).LastIndexOfAny(separators);
        if (lastloc > 6)
        {
            appname = imgprefix.Substring(lastloc + 1);
        }


        FMPAsset asset = new FMPAsset();

        //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\test.txt");

        XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyModel.XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyEntities markerCtx = new XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyModel.XSPPrinterMarkerSupplyEntities(b.BuildEntityConnectionString1("XSMDSN"));

        for (int x = 0; x < currentAssetsCount; x++)
        {
            asset = new FMPAsset();

            asset.AssetID = currentAssets[x].AssetID.ToString();
            asset.PricePlanID = currentAssets[x].PricePlanID.ToString();
            asset.AssociationID = currentAssets[x].AssociationID;
            asset.ModelName = currentAssets[x].ModelName;
            asset.ResponsibilityForAction = currentAssets[x].ResponsibilityForAction;
            asset.IPAddress = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAssets[x].PrinterIPAddress)) ? "No IP" : currentAssets[x].PrinterIPAddress; ;

            if (currentAssets[x].InScope)
            {
                asset.InScope = b.GetString("SDE_YES");
            }
            else
            {
                asset.InScope = b.GetString("SDE_NO");
            }

            asset = SetStatus(appname, asset, x);

            asset.PricePlanName = currentAssets[x].Program;
            asset.PricePlanDescription = currentAssets[x].PricePlanDescription;
            asset.ServicePlanName = currentAssets[x].ServicePlanName;

            if (currentAssets[x].PrinterSerialNumber != null)
            {
                asset.PrinterSerialNumber = currentAssets[x].PrinterSerialNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                asset.PrinterSerialNumber = "-";
            }

            //sw.WriteLine("ChargebackDescription: " + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            if (this.b.UseChargebackDescription && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAssets[x].CustomerChargebackDescription) && currentAssets[x].CustomerChargebackDescription != "Generated by OUT Integration")
            {
                asset.Customer = currentAssets[x].CustomerChargebackDescription;

                if (asset.Customer.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) > -1)
                {
                    asset.Customer = asset.Customer.Substring(0, asset.Customer.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                asset.Customer = currentAssets[x].CustomerChargeBackEntryName;
            }

            if (this.b.UsePricePlanDescription && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAssets[x].PricePlanDescription))
            {
                asset.Program = currentAssets[x].PricePlanDescription;
                if (asset.Program.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) > -1)
                {
                    asset.Program = asset.Program.Substring(0, asset.Program.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                asset.Program = currentAssets[x].Program;
            }

            asset.BlackPct = -3;
            asset.CyanPct = -3;
            asset.MagentaPct = -3;
            asset.YellowPct = -3;

            Guid id = currentAssets[x].AssetID;

            asset = SetCMYKvalues(asset, x);

            BuilldImpressionsValues(currentAssets[x], ref asset);
            fmpAssets.Add(asset);
        }

        var totalAssetCount = assets.Count();
        var y = new PagedResult<FMPAsset>();
        y.Records =  fmpAssets;
        y.TotalCount = totalAssetCount;
        return y;


        //           CommonGrid1.BindDataSource(SortByStatusName(fmpAssets));


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks; you might have more luck if you tagged this problem as Java or SQLServer or whatever.  Your current problem (and previous problem) are server problems - either with your SQL or your web service.  When you tag this as ExtJS, lots of people will not view it and maybe not ask the question that will provide you an answer.

Comment: sure i will tag it in others also.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening when your store is making the call to your web service.  Whatever JSON is being sent is not valid for some reason (or .NET does not think it is), hence the server error when ASP.NET is trying to deserialize the data into a valid argument list for your method.  I would first look in Firebug to see exactly what JSON is being passed to the server -- that might give you a clue as to what the issue is.  If the JSON being sent is not valid then it's a client/Ext issue -- if it is valid, then it's a .NET issue.